# Choose permalink on a per-post basis?

Tags: permalinks

I've set up a hosted wordpress on a server. The client told me he wants to be able to choose the permalink for each post as he claims he has this option on wordpress.org for another site of his.

He even sent me this screenshot
[image: alleged custom permalink per post]

I suspect this is not possible and that perhaps i am not understanding the true nature of this screenshot, does anyone recognize this? what is the plugin i need to install for this feature

Comment: It is there by default. You can also change the permalink or slug in the 'quick edit' box of a post. If you are not seeing it then maybe you have a plugin hiding it or something.

Comment: @Nath As an answer, please. Maybe including a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this. Some sort of bug was hiding it. Apparently all i had to do was checking "Post name" option under Settings > Permalinks as explained on http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-posts-returning-404-error/